# Facebook SDK Android keeps on loading

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am trying to integrate the facebook SDK given at

git://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git

and I have followed the complete guide given at developers.facebook.com

The project compiles fine, but when i debug it on my HTC Desire HD, the application starts and keeps on loading for a minute or so and then exits.

I am not able to figure out what is wrong, why am i not able to see the screens given at developers.facebook.com

Thanks for your help guys !

EDIT !!!

```
package com.greatapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.*;

public class MyGreatActivity extends Activity {

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("APP_ID"); // i added the app id in the original       

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        facebook.authorize(this, new Facebook.DialogListener() {

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onCancel() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Disable SSO. It can cause some pain at the beginning and use forced dialog -based auth. It should show on LogCat though if SSO is the reason for crash.

Comment: Did U add the internet permission in manifest file.

Comment: works on emulator? any code/logcat output?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> i added that ... @harism log cat has no red statements .. i think its all good there

Comment: check edit .. i added the class code

Comment: guys .. its working on emulator but not on my phone :s

Comment: It shouldn't take too long to disable SSO for testing purposes, try `Facebook.authorize(activity, permissions, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, observer)` and see what happens.

Comment: can you post the code, i am too confused :s

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you are not behind a firewall. Maybe that's why you could not get Facebook screen in your application.

Comment: Hey @Chadwick and @hardik pansuria, I tried implementing the FB login flow with the UILifeCycleHelper and in certain instances, the `data` param which would normally have a field `mMap`, which contains the FB response, is null.  Why would this be happening?